# Magento2 - Marketplace showing error but I have checked there is no error

Tags: magento2.3, magento2marketplace

I am getting the following error on the Marketplace.

Attached the screenshot of the error.

[image]

I have checked with update `Production` mode and no issue found.

Comment: ok on which version have you checked bro

Comment: I have checked in magento2.3.2 and php7.1

Comment: Try with php7.2, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/prereq-overview.html

Comment: As in screenshot it is saying Environment php7.1 and magento 2.3

Comment: I am getting error in submit extension in magento marketplace

Comment: Yes, have you checked with Magento 2.3?

Comment: Yes I have checked with magento 2.3.2, 2.3.1 and no error found

Comment: Please check in pages (where your extension code runs ) from network tab do you get X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS  when yo refresh page first time and get X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT when you refresh page second time